# Electron and webpack build with task

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron, package.json

I am building an application with:

- React `16.4.0`
- Electron `2.0.2`
- Webpack `4.11.0`
- webpack-dev-server `3.1.4`

This application uses hot-reload (as far as that is currently working...) for development. Every time I want to start my project I have to start 2 tasks right after eachother and it is getting annoying. There has to be a faster way. Is there any way I can start them with 1 node task and they startup after each other?

I must note that the dev server must be done with compiling before the electron app can be started.

---

**package.json**

```
 "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --hot",
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=development&& electron ."
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something like this on a recent project using `concurrently`.

```
$ npm i -SD concurrently
```

And then in your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --hot",
  "electron-dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development && electron .",
  "start": "concurrently --kill-others --names \"webpack,electron\" \"npm run dev-server\" \"npm run electron-dev\""
},
```

This does not, unfortunately, wait for the bundle to finish. But I find I can just hit reload (Ctrl/Cmd + R) once in the Electron app after the build finishes and I'm good to go.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!. 
You did forgot a comma after the `electron-dev` task and somehow I need to set the `&&` right after 'development' (NODE_ENV=development&&) otherwise I end up with an extra space after the name 'development'.